# How to create irrational endpoints of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ from countable basis

Tags: general-topology

I read that $\mathbb{R}$ has a countable basis (i.e. it's second countable). The countable basis consists of open intervals with rational endpoints. Now, from this countable basis, how do you construct open sets (intervals) with irrational endpoints?

Comment: Seeing how there are now two deleted answers which misread your question. How about improving it somehow?

Comment: Seeing as there are two good answers, improving the question is not needed other than removing "..." and replacing it with a period.

Comment: what do you mean by "open intervals are rational numbers". How could an open interval (containing many numbers) be the same as a single number (rational or not). So, what do you refer to, when you say "this set" in "...open intervals with irrational endpoints from this set". I can't make sense of your question. I cannot relate the answers given to your question.

Comment: Ok those are good points, will edit the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(u_n)$ be a descending sequence of rationals converging to $a$.

Let $(v_n)$ be an ascending sequence of rationals converging to $b$.

$$(a,b) = \bigcup_n (u_n, v_n)\text{.}$$

Answer (score 3):

$(a,b)=\bigcup \{(p,q): p,q\in \Bbb Q\cap (a,b)\}.$